# My tSQLt scripts gets overwritten when prod db refresh happens? How to persist the tsqlt script?

Tags: unit-testing, sql-server-2012, tdd, clr, tsqlt

I have tsqlt installed on lower environments and I have created my tsqlt for the unit testing. But right now, we don't promote tSQLt to production since we are not allowed to install tSQLt in production db. But after every release, our dba team will refresh the lower environment with production data and hence our lower environment tSQLt script gets overwritten. How do I persist in my tsqlt in the lower environments? Any thoughts or solutions?

Comment: I suggest you keep your unit test scripts in source control and re-deploy after a refresh.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes. That's what I am doing right now but it takes a few hours to redeploy my tsqlt script back in the lower environment after every DB refresh.

Comment: @DanGuzman Is there a way, can push the tsqlt script to production without executing tsqlt test cases on production and flow back tsqlt scripts to the lower environment via the lower environment (without installing tsqlt and not enabling CLR in Prod db)

Comment: It is not normal to take hours to redeploy tSQLt unit tests. Installation and deployment of unit tests is separate than executing them. It seems my may be running the unit tests too and it takes a long time against a large prod database copy.

Comment: we have 100's of tsqlt test stored proc and it takes time to re-run on the lower environment.

Comment: Creating 100‘s of stored procedures should take seconds, not hours. Is it possible that your scripts not only create the procedures, but also run the tests with tSQLt.Run? I’ve seen developers put an `EXEC tSQLt.Run` at the end of test creation scripts in an attempt to save time. 

If that is not the case, we’ll need more detail about your environment to be able to help.

Comment: @SebastianMeine Yes, we do tSQLt.Run. Every time, we have to rerun the tsqlt scripts and I was looking for any other persistent options that exist?

Comment: Just to clarify: There are two things that need to happen in a refreshed environment. One is to install tSQLt itself and all the tests. The other one is to execute those tests using `tSQLt.Run`. Which of the two takes hours?

Comment: @SebastianMeine Option 1: To install all tSQLt tests. tSQLT software was persistent but we lost all the test cases.

Comment: Are your tests all in one file or in multiple files? How many tests? How many files? What are the hardware specs of the sql server that you are trying to do this on? Is that a dedicated machine, or does other stuff run on it? How big is the database?